# return a string from javascript function into html

Tags: javascript, html

I have select tag to have a drop down list, so when user submits the expiration year of his credit card he has a drop down list to select a year.

I am planning to have a long term web site and as year grows I will have to update manually the years, so I am thinking to make something with JavaScript so it returns current year

so far I have a jscript function that returns the year and I want the html to get the year from the options tags. sample code I tried

```
 <script>
    function getDate(){
       return new Date().getFullYear();
    }
 </script>
 <select id="year">
    <option value="">Year</option>
    <option value="getDate()">getDate()</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: `->`: http://www.w3.org/wiki/Creating_and_modifying_HTML. I suggest to  have a look at some tutorials about how to do DOM manipulation with JavaScript.

Comment: You mistyped `function` and your code will not work otherwise.

Comment: Javascript is event-based, it won't get called unless you tie it to an event. For example, you could set the value of this option on page load, when the user clicks an element, when an element changes, etc.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3LBPe/

Comment: cgatian, please post that as an answer ;) Seemed to make the trick.

Comment: @mico  The OP asks to make a function that returns the current year, therefore my answer makes sense more.

Comment: @Goose How is that? JS doesn't even have any methods/objects for event handling (see [DOM Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM_Client_Object_Cross-Reference/DOM_Events)). Though interaction between JS and browser is more or less event- based, JavaScript itself is not event-based.

Comment: @Teemu Maybe I chose poor wording, but my point was that the function won't do anything unless something calls it.

Comment: @Goose I absolutely agree with that : ). Also looks like your answer is the only proper answer here yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your getDate function won't do anything unless triggered. There are many many ways to accomplish this, the following example adds an option of the current year to your select menu on body `onload()` event.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function getDate() {
    var year = document.getElementById('year');
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.text = new Date().getFullYear();
    year.add(option,null);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="getDate()">
<select id="year">
    <option value="">Year</option>
 </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that populate the select with the current yeah and the next 10 years, you can change it in the for, you only need to call it once the page is loaded:

```
<head>
    <script>
        function addOptions() {
    var cmbYears = document.getElementById('year');

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var y = new Date().getFullYear() + i;
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.value = y;
        opt.innerHTML = y;
        cmbYears.appendChild(opt);
    }
}
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="addOptions()">
    <select id="year"></select>
</body>
```

What it does is, place the select in a var, then loop and create the option adding different years each time.

Edit: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Aem5P/1/)

Comment: thanx for your reply, but how do I actually call it to populate?

Comment: Place the function into your <script> and add addOptions(); after !

Comment: well it did look that obvious to me but <select id="year"> addOptions(); </select> does not work

Comment: see my edit, i added the call for the event and updated the fiddle to show you how it's working

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually put the date into something on the HTML page, not just expect it to populate the `<select>`

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Get a Date</title>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <script>
         function getDate() {
            var dateText = document.getElementById("dateText");
            var myDate = new Date();
            dateText.innerHTML = myDate.getFullYear();
         }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="dateText"></div>
      <button onclick="getDate()">Get Date</button>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your fixed code:

```
<script>
function getDate(){
       return new Date().getFullYear();
    }
 </script>
 <select id="year">
    <option value="">Year</option>
    <option value="getDate()" onclick = "document.body.innerHTML = getDate()">getDate()</option>
 </select>
```

First of all: `function` was spelled wrong.

Second:  You set `value` to `getDate()` not `onclick`.  Fixing that fixed your code.

I set `onclick` to make the page say the ouput (the year), however I don't know what you wanted.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m8kBt/

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="select_year"></select>

<script type="text/javascript">
thisyear=new Date().getFullYear();
numberofyear=15;
for(i=0; i<=numberofyear; i++)
{
    node=document.getElementById("select_year");
    var option=document.createElement("option");
    option.text=(thisyear+i);
    option.value=(thisyear+i);
    node.add(option,null);
}
</script>
```

this script insert into select value from 2013 to 2028... :D
and year update automatically each visit of a user

Comment: That's not what the OP asks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking the solution in jquery then here is your solution

```
$(function(){
var year = new Date().getFullYear();
var options=[];
    for(var i=0;i<15;i++)
    {
        options.push("<option value=\""+(year+i)+"\">"+(year+i)+"</option>");
    }
    $("#ddlyear").html(options.join(''));
});
```

This will always fill the dropdown with 15 years from now.

you can check the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9LMue/)